# How to determine whether the redirect link is secure or not?

Tags: http, url-redirection

I am checking about the security of redirect link, For the below link , how to determine whether it is secure?

For the first link, the users are not allowed to change the url in the browser, but they can copy the url down, open a new tab and paste it and change the value (but it is useless for attacking?)

For the second, it is a return path and the users can change it to any other value

[Example redirect link 1](http://testfire.net/disclaimer.htm?url=http://www.netscape.com)

[Example redirect link 2](http://testfire.net/servererror.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/bank/customize.aspx.cs)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by secure? In general terms, it doesn't matter how you get input into your application, it just matters that you don't ever trust it.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't explain what you mean by secure, so it is hard to answer your question.  Please see [the FAQ](https://security.stackexchange.com/faq) for advice on how to ask questions.

But that said, here are some resources on general risks with open, unrestricted redirects:

- Open redirect vulnerabilities, pp.43-45 of [Insecure magazine](http://www.net-security.org/dl/insecure/INSECURE-Mag-17.pdf)
- [OWASP on open redirects](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Open_redirect)
- [Open redirect CWE description](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/601.html)
- [An argument that open redirects are not a problem, or at worst are a minor issue](http://scarybeastsecurity.blogspot.com/2010/06/open-redirectors-some-sanity.html)
- [Example of an open redirect used for phishing](http://news.netcraft.com/open-redirect-detection/)
- [A mailing list with some thoughtful discussion on whether open redirects are really a serious problem or not](http://seclists.org/fulldisclosure/2011/Dec/185)
- [An example of a XSS attack on many forums that was facilitated by an open redirect in Youtube](http://sirdarckcat.blogspot.com/2007/09/universal-youtube-mods-xss-explained-in.html)

These may help understand the potential security risks associated with open redirects.

Please understand that there is debate about whether open redirects are a serious problem worth worrying about or not.  Many people would say that they pose little risk to the site that hosts the open redirect and aren't worth too much energy to fuss over.